# Read response header from WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, header, response, webclient

I'm trying to create my first windows client (and this is my fist post her), there shall communicate with a "web services", but i have some trouble to read the response header there is coming back. In my response string do I received a nice JSON document back (and this is my next problem), but i'm not able to "see/read" the header in the response, only the body.

Below is the code i'm using.

```
        WebClient MyClient = new WebClient();
        MyClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        MyClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "DIMS /0.1 +http://www.xxx.dk");
        var urlstring = "http://api.xxx.com/users/" + Username.Text;
        string response = MyClient.DownloadString(urlstring.ToString());
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use WebClient.ResponseHeaders like this:

```
// Obtain the WebHeaderCollection instance containing the header name/value pair from the response.
WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = myWebClient.ResponseHeaders;

Console.WriteLine("\nDisplaying the response headers\n");
// Loop through the ResponseHeaders and display the header name/value pairs. 
for (int i=0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)             
    Console.WriteLine ("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.Get(i));
```

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is the most relevant and correct answer for a WebClient object (which was the OP's question). I don't see why there was a need in this case to refer to HttpWebRequest or HttpWebResponse objects.

Comment: for sh!ts and giggle, if someone is using RestSharp and comes across this post you would do something like this with the return headers (tested and works):

for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++)
{
headerString = headerString + response.Headers[i].Name + ": " + response.Headers[i].Value + ((char)10);
}

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the full response, I suggest you use `WebRequest`/`WebResponse` instead of `WebClient`. That's a more low-level API - `WebClient` is meant to make very simple tasks (such as downloading the body of a response as a string) simple.

(Or in .NET 4.5 you could use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of how to use WebRequest/WebResponse, which is what *@Jon Skeet* was talking about.

```
var urlstring = "http://api.xxx.com/users/" + Username.Text;
var MyClient = WebRequest.Create(urlstring) as HttpWebRequest;
//Assuming your using http get.  If not, you'll have to do a bit more work.
MyClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
MyClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
MyClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "DIMS /0.1 +http://www.xxx.dk");
var response = MyClient.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

for (int i = 0; i < response.Headers.Count; i++ )
     Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.GetKey(i) + " -- " + response.Headers.Get(i).ToString());
```

Also I really recommend you abstract the http logic out to it's own object and pass in url, UserAgent and ContentType.

Answer (score 4):

This also works too

```
string acceptEncoding = client.ResponseHeaders["Accept"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way using WebClient(), combined with the MSDN example as mentioned above (the MSDN example does not explicitly explain how to initiate the request). Don't be confused by the `Properties.Settings.Default.XXXX` values, these are just string variables read from the App.settings file. I hope it helps:

```
using (var client = new WebClient()){
    try{
        var webAddr = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerEndpoint;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending to WebService " + webAddr);

        //This only applies if the URL access is secured with HTTP authentication
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.SecuredBy401Challenge)
             client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Properties.Settings.Default.UserFor401Challenge, Properties.Settings.Default.PasswordFor401Challenge);

        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
        client.OpenRead(webAddr);

        // Obtain the WebHeaderCollection instance containing the header name/value pair from the response.
        WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = client.ResponseHeaders;
        Console.WriteLine("\nDisplaying the response headers\n");

        // Loop through the ResponseHeaders and display the header name/value pairs.
        for (int i = 0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.Get(i));
    }
    catch (Exception exc){
        Console.WriteLine( exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is very similar to the MSDN documentation but I use `Headers` instead of the `ResponseHeaders` and didn't receive the null reference exception that I received when running the MSDN code. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders(v=vs.110).aspx

```
        WebClient MyClient = new WebClient();
        MyClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        MyClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "DIMS /0.1 +http://www.xxx.dk");

        WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = MyClient.Headers;
        for (int i = 0; i < myWebHeaderCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t" + myWebHeaderCollection.GetKey(i) + " = " + myWebHeaderCollection.Get(i));
        }
```