# Read response header using RestSharp API in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, restsharp

I have a REST web service which produces media of type MULTIPART_FORM_DATA as response and JSON in the the response header. What is the easiest way to read this response header (JSON) using RestSharp REST API client?

Is there a similar way to do this using RestClient like following in .NET 4?

```
response.Headers.GetKey(i);
response.Headers.Get(i).ToString()
```

(Reference: first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22024233/read-response-header-from-webclient-in-c-sharp))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way to do it and it's working fine.

```
response.Headers.ElementAt(i).Name.ToString();    
response.Headers.ElementAt(i).Value.ToString();
```